# Using lambda to pull image from Docker hub and push to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

Our code deployment pipeline uses ECR to maintain images and there are some public images that we use from Docker hub.
We would manually pull the images and then push to ECR. I would like to automate this process by pulling the latest image from Docker hub and pushing it to ECR through Lambda.

Using [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) Python library seems to one way of doing it.
Is there another simpler way to download the image from Docker hub in the Lambda?
Thank you.

Comment: CodeBuild would be better in my view. Are you sure you can store the images in lambda (max 500 MB)? Also I'm not sure if docker-py requires docker daemon running on lambda?

Comment: Thank you.
I was thinking i could download to S3 first. But then maybe thats not possible.

Comment: In my view CB would be simpler and more straight forward to use. Even if you can do it in lambda (not sure), it would require more exercise, especially if you want to include S3 into the mix.

Comment: Thank you Marcin. Do you mean Use CB to download from Docker hub?

Comment: Yes. This would be my first solution to try. And if this does not work as expected, then consider alternative ways.

Comment: No problem. Please let me know how it will go and if you have other questions. If everything works out I could later provide an answer.

Comment: Along @Marcin good comment, here is a AWS Sample project that uses CodeBuild to accomplish replication from Docker to ECR:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecr-replication-for-pub-container-images